# Поддержка HTTPS на сайте

Tags: php, https

На протяжении нескольких лет делал сайты на http (протокол). И вот сейчас нужно сделать платежную систему по протоколу https. У меня на сервере стоит isp manadger (там вроде есть кое какие настройки).

- Куда и как заливать сайт, чтоб он работал через https?
- Какие отличия с точки зрения программирования при размещении сайта на https?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы меня только что оскорбили фразой  "вопрос кстати не нубский, а вот **читают его похоже умные нубы**". Я уже было собирался ответить Вам более развернуто. Но отвечу так, умник:

Для того, чтобы настроить https нужно купить(есть бесплатные) сертификат.(где купить ищи в гугле).

Затем указать серверу(apache/nginx/etc) что нужно использовать сертификат(как это сделать ищи в гугле).

Ну и обращаться к страницам через https://адрес.сайта

Comment: Автор видимо не понимает, что хочет. Платежную систему можно "подключить", но никак не сделать (подразумеваем, что такие вопросы бы сразу отпали на более важные). Я бы посоветовал нанять человека, чтобы тот всё сделал красиво за 15 минут, ибо я в первый раз сломал конфиг апача и убил 3 часа на восстановление, хотя так и не восстановил. Лучше отдать каких-то 6 евро за настройку.

Comment: @KryDos, а ведь по сути-то ТС **прав**. Ничего лучшего, как послать в гугл Вы сказать не смогли.

Comment: @avp, простите, я что-то Вашего комментария не понял. 

Правильно будет не "Вы сказать не смогли" а "Вы не сказали" :)

В гугле по запросу "как настроить https на сайте" есть все ответы. 

Стоило бы сказать, что платежную систему нужно подключать а не писать самому. Тут я не прав :(

Comment: @KryDos, мне почему-то хочется, чтобы на форуме были по возможности **полезные ответы**, а не советы поискать или что-нибудь почитать. 

Полемику же с автором видимо лучше вести в комментариях (хотя их лимит ограничен и это IMHO плохо).

Ну, ссылку на *конкретный* материал видимо можно считать *полезным* ответом.

Comment: @avp, во мне говорила обида. Буду стараться быть более полезным.